# Programatic Creation and Config of UITabBarController - Setting a system Image for a tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

Creating a tabBar in an app programatically is fairly easy:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 
[self.view addSubview:_tabBarController.view];

UIViewController * tab1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
tab1.title = "A";

UIViewController * tab2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
tab2.title = "B";

_tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:patientSearch,todoList,nil];

[tab1 release];
[tab2 release];
```

You can also easily put images in the tabs:

```
tab1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myIcon.png"];
```

**However how can i set the image of these tabs to one the system images?** (eg. search, favourite, bookmarks etc.) In IB this is set by changing the 'identifier' but how can you do this programatically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 UITabBarItem *aTabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:0];
```

UITabBarItem [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> UITabBarSystemItem
>   System items that can be used on a tab bar.

```
typedef enum {
   UITabBarSystemItemMore,
   UITabBarSystemItemFavorites,
   UITabBarSystemItemFeatured,
   UITabBarSystemItemTopRated,
   UITabBarSystemItemRecents,
   UITabBarSystemItemContacts,
   UITabBarSystemItemHistory,
   UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks,
   UITabBarSystemItemSearch,
   UITabBarSystemItemDownloads,
   UITabBarSystemItemMostRecent,
   UITabBarSystemItemMostViewed,
} UITabBarSystemItem;
```

To set it `patientSearch.tabBarItem = aTabBarItem;`

Comment: what is the use case of `tag`?